# Hemisphere Projection

Tags: opengl, mathematics, projection

I came across the following segment of code that is supposed to project an image on a hemisphere:

```
void main(void)
{
    vColor = aColor;
    vec4 pos = uModelViewMatrix * vertex;
    float lenxy = length(pos.xy);
    if(lenxy != 0.0)
    {
       float phi = atan(lenxy, -pos.z);
       pos.xy = normalize(pos.xy);
       // pos.xy is equal to (cos theta, sin theta)
       float r = phi / (PI/2.);
       // radius is less than or equal to 1.
       pos.xy *= r; 
       // same theta, different radius
    }
    gl_Position = uProjectionMatrix * pos;
 }
```

The followings are what I need clarifications for:

1. Why would `r` be less than or equal to `1` by dividing `phi` by `PI/2.`?
2. Why are we multiplying `pos.xy` with `r`?
3. And, how does normalizing `pos.xy` give us cos theta and sin theta?

The followings are the accompanying images:

[image]

---

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The value `r` will be between -1 and 1 because the `atan()` function returns a value between -π/2 and π/2. (Actually, that's probably the `atan2()` function since it takes 2 parameters.)

If you think back to basic trigonometry, sine and cosine functions are defined by the ratios of the radius of the circle to the length of either the horizontal or vertical sides of the right triangle they form. Or to put it more simply:

> sine(theta) = opposite / hypotenuse
>
> cosine(theta) = adjacent / hypotenuse

(The images in the [Wikipedia article on sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine) explain it pretty well.)

In a unit circle, the hypotenuse is always a length of 1, by definition. So by normalizing the vector `pos`, its length becomes 1 and the x and y components of the vector become the lengths of the sides of the right triangle used to define sine and cosine (the opposite and adjacent sides in the above definitions). Like this:

[image: Trigonometry]

As mentioned, `sine(theta) = opposite / hypotenuse`. Since this is a unit circle, the hypotenuse of that triangle has a length of 1. So `sine(theta) = opposite / 1.0` or just `opposite`. And `opposite` is a line from normalized (`pos.x`, `pos.y`) straight down to the y axis. So the length of `opposite` is (normalized) `pos.y`. Likewise, `cosine(theta) = adjacent / hypotenuse`, which is just `adjacent`, which has a length of (normalized) `pos.x`.

So if `r` is now a value between -1 and 1, and you multiply the normalized `pos` by it, you'll get a vector of length `r` pointing in the direction of `pos`.

Comment: I've added an image which I hope makes it clearer. As for why dividing `phi` by `PI/2` makes the result less than or equal to one - that's what I explained in the very first sentence. The `atan()` function returns a value between -π/2 and +π/2. So if you divide that value by π/2, the result will be somewhere between -1.0 and 1.0.

Comment: I should clarify that the `atan()` function returns the arctangent of its input(s).

Comment: I believe that will flip the image horizontally.

Comment: Let's ignore the sign for a moment; here's what I find unsettling: given the 2nd image above, shouldn't we be using `arccos` to find `phi` instead of `atan`? The angle is subtended by the hypothenuse (`lengthXY`) and the adjacent (`pos.z`); so, shouldn't it rather be using `acos(lengthXY, -pos.z)`?

Comment: You use atan2 to get the sign. It's not possible to get the sign with anything other than atan2. The sign is very important so that your resulting vector points in the right direction and there's no acos2 or asin2. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094261/why-are-there-no-asin2-and-acos2-functions-similar-to-atan2

Comment: @BjornTipling I understand that we need to get the sign using `atan2`, and using `arccos` or `arcsin` is simply not feasible. However, we couldn't simply use `atan2` just because we cannot use `arccos` and `arcsin`, correct? If you would look at the 2nd attached image, the author is feeding the `atan2` with the hypothenuse and adjacent sides, which corresponds to `arccos`. If you could be able to make sense out of it, please share. Thanks.

Comment: I think `lenxy` must be the vertical line and not the hypotenuse as given in that second diagram. I can't see where x is. The length of that hypotenuse would be the square root of `z^2 + y^2`. But why would vertical line be the length of y and x? I'm not sure, it doesn't look like a well drawn diagram.